# Set working dir in both interactive (Rstudio) and non-interactive (knitr) use in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am working on a general pipeline that would be run across many projects and would like to use Rmarkdown notebooks to generate the final reports.

So my directory structure might look something like:

```
/home/user/devel/pipelines/
  | - pipeline1/
  | - pipeline2/
  | - pipeline3/
       | - .git
       | - default_configuration.ini
       | - processing_pipeline.py
       | - report.Rmd

/cluster/lustre/projects/
  | - project1/
  | - project2/
  | - project3/
        | - data/
        | - pipeline1_results/
        | - pipeline2_results/
        | - pipeline3_results/
             | - configuration.ini
             | - results.tsv.gz
             | - results... [VARIOUS ANALYSIS PRODUCTS]
             | - [finished report will go here]....
```

In the ideal world, i'd like to keep the Rmarkdown source in the `devel` directory, under version control. I'd like to develop the report interactively in Rstudio on an example data set, using the Rstudio working directory rather than the location of the `Rmd` as the working dir and for future data sets have it knit using a script command and use the current directory as the working directory without changing any code.

I can acomplish the first part by putting something like:

````
```{r setup}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir="/cluster/lusture/projects/project3/pipeline3/")
```
````

But now I've hard coded the notebook to run in a particular directory, not just whatever the working directory of the R session is, so this fails when I want to run on a different project (probably knitting in batch mode).

I can accomplish the last part by having my pipeline execute something like:

```
Rscript -e 'library(rmarkdown);
opts_knit$set(root.dir = ".");
render("/path/to/source/report.Rmd")'
```

in the analysis directory. But that doesn't work for an interactive session.

I'd also like the report.Rmd to try to load the `configuration.ini` from the currently directory, and if it doesn't exist load it from the source directory. But I don't know how to get the source directory in the Rmd in a way that will work in both interactive sessions and when knitting.